# Adding MULTIPLE divs on a button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is it possible to add a div to the HTML page without PHP? Every time the button is pressed I would like for a div to appear. If the button is clicked 2 times there should be two divs, if pressed three times three divs should be added, etc.

```
<a id="add_txt" class="btn">Add Text</a>
```

ADD WHEN BUTTON IS CLICKED:

```
<div class="ui_move">
    <input class="txt_s" />
</div>
```

-Sorry if there are any mistakes in my writing, I was in a rush.

Comment: Which part are you having an issue with?  Capturing the click event, or creating the new markup?

Comment: Javascript is definitely what is needed. Can you provide any code that you have tried?

Comment: I thought you wanted to add a `div`? How come you're adding an `input`? Kidding aside, please take a look at the link @James provided. It will solve your problem.

Comment: @James I can't express this enough,  like I stated it should be on the HTML page not the container.

Comment: @Taplar Creating new markup.

Comment: Well, the container is on the HTML page so all good right?  Otherwise you need to be a lot more specific in your question (exactly where you want the new divs inserted, showing surrounding HTML, and the reason why you can't use a container)